# Is there a way to query a struct's keys without initializing the struct?

Tags: rust

Given a struct:

```
pub struct Link {
    pub text: String,
    pub title: String,
    pub url: String,
}
```

Is there a way to find out what the keys are at runtime?

Comment: Not at runtime, yes at compile time.

Comment: While researching this I found this compile time reflection project as a potential solution: https://github.com/8BitMate/reflect